# How do you instantiate an inner class of a static nested class?

Tags: java, class

This is my class

```
public class XYZ{

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        int n = 5;
        Object myObject;
       //somehow call returnN(n);
    } //end main

    static class Inner{
        private class Private{
            private int returnN(int n){
                return n;
            }
        }
    }//end of Inner


}
```

I am trying to call returnN from main. I've tried `myObject = new XYZ.Inner.Private();` but this does not appear to be the correct instantiation.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`Private` is not `static`. Therefore you need an instance of `Inner` before you can create a `Private`. The correct syntax is

```
new XYZ.Inner().new Private().returnN(3);
```

Alternatively, you can make `Private` `static` and then you can just do

```
new XYZ.Inner.Private().returnN(3);
```

Comment: "Private is not static" -- I know that it isn't static, but Inner is, and to my understanding, a static class is a sort of "shared instance," so using "()" isn't needed, so why can't I do new XYZ.Inner.Private()?

Comment: Also why does it allow me to do myObject = new XYZ.Inner().new Private(); but then I cannot do myObject.returnN(3); ?

Comment: A static nested class is not a shared instance. A static nested class is really just like a top-level class except it happens to be defined inside another class. On the other hand, an instance of an inner class can be thought of as belonging to the enclosing instance.

Comment: You can't do `myObject.returnN(3);` because the type of `myObject` is `Object`, and `Object` doesn't have a method `returnN`.

Comment: Is there no way for me to call returnN from myObject after setting it to the inner private class?

Comment: You can do `Inner.Private myObject = new Inner().new Private();`. `myObject.returnN(3);`

Answer (score 0):

Sean: why did you delete your [recent question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/33643584/how-to-structure-this-in-java) after Alain put in effort to answer it? I will post it here so that it at least has an internet presence, but you should re-open it, and up-vote Alain's answer, at least for the effort he put into answering it.

---

## Question

I am supposed to implement a class, when I have lines like this:

```
double v = className.functionName().main(a,b);
```

And

```
className.output.display(v);
```

It is not clear to me what this hierarchy is supposed to look like in the className class.

What does it mean to call main() from a function call? Calling a main function from a function? Why possibly isnt this just functionName(a,b)?

And the point of using .output.? Is this supposed to be a void with a sub-function display()?

---

## Alain's Answer

Answer by [Alain O'Dea](https://stackoverflow.com/users/154527/alain-odea)

**output** is a field.  There is no such thing as a sub-function or method, there are just methods on objects.  The **display()** method is on the **object** field of the **classname** object.

The **main()** method here is just a method on the object returned by **functionName()**.  There is no special meaning from being called **main()**.

I would infer something like this from the lines given:

I'm going to assume that **className** is an instance of **ClassName** used like this:

```
public class Main {
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        ClassName className = new ClassName();
        Object a = new Object(); // replace with correct a
        Object b = new Object(); // replace with correct b
        double v = className.functionName().main(a,b);
        className.output.display(v);
    }
}
```

And ClassName would be defined as follows:

```
public class ClassName {
    public Output output = new Output;
    public Mainable functionName() {
        return new Mainable();
    }
}
```

Output.java:

```
public class Output {
    public void display(double v) {
        // implement display here
    }
}
```

Mainable.java:

```
public class Mainable {
    public double main(Object a, Object b) {
        return 0.0d; // put actual impl here
    }
}
```